# Overlapping div positioning using css

Tags: html, css

There are 4 `divs` as shown in the image. Red, green and blue. I want blue `div` positioned right under the green `div` that has "JACKSON" content and also don't want green `div` expand neither red `div`. And I also want to center blue `div` according "JACKSON" text. Blue `div` will be on the other `divs` like `z-index` of blue `div` will have a higher value than the other `divs`. I want to do this using just `css`.

> Note: `Divs` won't have `width` and `height` pixel values.

[image]

Comment: Not everyone can see images. Include a http://jsfiddle.net/ and your code in the question to get more help.

Comment: unfortunately, image is a must. And it can not be explained in jsfiddle.

Comment: You mean you either can't or won't use `HTML` and `CSS` to create an example for us? I hope you find someone who is willing to provide you with a solution even though you demonstrated an unwillingness to put in the work. Also, red, green and blue is 3 `divs`, not 4.

Comment: what you are saying has no logic! if you look at my previous questions you will see that i am asking detailed questions!

Comment: red, green, green and blue!

Comment: how can i show the codes that i can not even know how to do???

Comment: I apologize for upsetting you.

Comment: that is why i added image!

Comment: It is really hard to know what you need but I approach in my answer. See it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to center the blue `div` with the JACKSON `div` you could use `CSS3` transforms. With this technique no matter the size of the green `divs` the blue `div` will be centered (put the rest of `css` prefixes):

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="green">
    DAVID
  </div>
  <div class="green">
    JACKSON
    <div class="blue">
      WHO IS DAVID AND JACKSON?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red, .green, .blue{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.red{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.green{
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.blue{
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/Lhts9gmy/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I'm sure you can figure out how to tweak this to your needs. It is pretty basic CSS.

The key to "overlapping" your `div` would be using `margin` or a combination of `position` and either `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` CSS properties.

```css
.red, .green, .blue {border: solid 4px; display: inline-block;}
.red {border-color: red;}
.green {border-color: green; margin-bottom: 1em;}
.blue {border-color: blue;}
.blue {margin-left: 2em; position: relative; top:-1em;}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="green">David</div>
  <div class="green">Jackson</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="blue">Who is David and Jackson?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you need something like this?

```css
.red {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.green {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.blue {
  width: 35%;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="green">David</div>
  <div class="green">Jackson</div>
</div>
<div class="blue">Who are David and Jackson?</div>
```